# Angular ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in dynamically created component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2, angular5

I am facing an Issue with Angular and the `CdkPortal`/`CdkPortalHost` from `@angular/cdk`.
I created a service, which allowes me to register a `CdkPortalHost` with a given name and set it's `Component` in any moment.

The service looks like this:

```
private portalHosts : { [location : string] : CdkPortalOutlet } = {};
private portals : { [location : string] : any} = {};

/** Sets the PortalHost for the given location. */
public register(location : string, portalHost : CdkPortalOutlet) {
    this.portalHosts[location] = portalHost;
}

/** Sets the Component for the given location. */
public setComponent<T>(location : string, type : ComponentType<T>) : ComponentRef<T> {
    let ref : ComponentRef<T> = null;
    let portalHost = this.portalHosts[location];
    if (portalHost) {
        if (portalHost.hasAttached()) {
            portalHost.portal.detach();
            this.portals[location] = null;
        }
        ref = portalHost.attachComponentPortal(new ComponentPortal(type));
        this.portals[location] = ref.instance;
    }
    return ref;
}
```

Then I registered a PortalHost like this:

```
@ViewChild(PortalHostDirective)
private portalHost : PortalHostDirective;

public ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.dynamicComponentService.register("Location", this.portalHost);
}
```

In an other Component, which is a child of the Component that registers the PortalHost, I set the dynamic Component like this:

```
public ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.dynamicComponentService.setComponent("Location", MyDynamicComponent);
}
```

For testing-purposes I use a simple template for the MyDynamicComponent:

```
<div *ngIf="true">Test</div>
```

Now, when I run the App, I get the following error:

```
Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.
Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: 'true'.
It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked.
Has it been created in a change detection hook ?
```

I have seen a few similar questions, but the "window.setTimeout"-Workaround did not work for me.
Also I tryed differed lifecycle-hooks for the PortalHost-Registration and the Component-Creation but the result was always the same...

I am using Angular 5.0.1 and Material/CDK 5.0.0-rc0.

Am I missing something or is this a bug?
Is it related to [Angular/Material#5268](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5268)

Comment: Try replacing `*ngIf` with `[hidden]`: so instead of `*ngIf="true"` you'd have `[hidden]="true"`

Comment: The *ngIf was just an example. I actually need a much more compöex componenz which uses *ngFor to render a list of items I get over http.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I'm trying to attach a portal to a portalHost and it doesn't like <span>{{title}}</span>

Comment: No, I didn't find a solution yet. I guess, that it is a bug in @angular or in the cdk. I sent a minimal example to an angular expert who I know and I will probably open an Issue in @angular/material. I'll update this as soon as I know something. But until then, I don't think it's an Issue, as it does not seem to have an effect in the prod build...

Answer (score 0):

`ngAfterContentInit` may be too early for the change detection of the portal outlet to take effect. I experienced this exact isuue when registering the portal outlet *and* register a component to it in an `ngOnInit`:

```js
this.tabPortalHost = new DomPortalOutlet(
  this.tabContentOutlet.nativeElement,
  this.componentFactoryResolver,
  this.appRef,
  this.injector
);


const portal = new ComponentPortal(this.tabs[0], null, this.injector);
this.tabPortalHost.attach(portal);
```

When wrapping the last line in a `setTimeout`, the code works as expected.